# Decipher the message

Tags: cipher, language

Message:

2519977! 61 1315079 799!

clues:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet

https://translate.google.com/

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! As your two clues point to language resources, I added a "Language" tag to your question.   You may want to take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and look around at other questions to get a feel for how others ask compelling questions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> "This is the case"

If you:

> match the number with the letter in the alphabet and render it through google translator

that is what you get

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  I added spoiler tags to your question (using the characters >! before each hidden line) so other people don't see it before they choose.

Comment: @puzzledPig you proposed it :) Faris just needs to click accept.

Comment: @thecoder16 true, poor wording on my part :)

Comment: Cool! =D wasn't what i was looking for though =/